# MS Excel: How to get a string of repeating letters from a bigger string?

Tags: microsoft-excel

After my measurements I end up with a row of failed and passed tests (`x` = failed, `o` = passed).
This row starts with `x` or `o` and changes one time.

```
Example A) xxxoo
Example B) ooox
Example C) ooxxxxx
```

I am now searching for a function that gives me the second part of the string where all letters are the same up to a maximum of 4 letters.
So the results will be:

```
A) oo
B) x
C) xxxx
```

I know that I can get the last digits with `RIGHT()` but I don't know how to check for the length of the "only `x`" or "only `o`" part at the end.

Comment: Well done for showing a very clear example with the results you would expect, which made the problem much easier to address in detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the constraints on your data, where there is **only a single transition**, you can just repeat the rightmost character the number of times it exists in your string:

```
=REPT(RIGHT(A1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,RIGHT(A1),"")))
```

[image]

*Not sure if the "four letters" refers to a data constraint or a formula function, but if there might be more than four letters, and you only want to return the last four, then embed the above formula in a RIGHT function: `=right(the_formula,4)`**

Comment: Yes by definition there is only one transition so this is a very nice way to do it.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

If the string can only change once, then all you need to do is "throw away" the left hand characters, then limit the remainder to 4. "Substitute" will swap a string for another, so you can swap the leftmost character for nothing, however many times it appears.

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,LEFT(A1,1),""),4)
```

If the string could change zero times eg ooooo or xxxxxx then this will give an empty result. This might be considered correct if you only ever want the *second* letter since there isn't one.

Comment: Also a nice solution. By definition, there will always be one and only one transition.